# how to identify mime type handlers in google chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

So I saw a question here that got me thinking, and long story short I'm trying to figure out how to embed xterm into google chrome using mozplugger. (I may be nuts but that is a separate question.) This appears to possibly be theoretically possible, but I have a couple related questions.

1. How do i determine from a running instance of chrome what mime types a plugin will handle? `about:plugins` will tell me which plugins are installed but not what mime types they handle.
2. How do I determine what plugin/extension/external program/whatever will handle a given mime type?
3. How do i change it?
4. Bonus: (slightly unrelated) does chrome cache this information anywhere that would need updated if I modify a plugin to handle additional mime types without reinstalling?

also should be tagged mozplugger.